# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in a chain of referensing components

Tags: angular

`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` in a chain of referencing components.

I have a service that is polling a data from `REST API` and store it in a cache. Several components are connected together using `#` referencing or `@ViewChild` in one chain. The first component is reading data from the service doing calculations and passing results to the next one. The calculated data is presented in each component letting me control if the calculations are right.

I'm not using `ngAfterViewInit`. But getting an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` in a very last component.

It can be represent like this:

component A ( output)-read output of the previous component-> component B ( output)-read output of the previous component-> component C ( output)-read data from service->service(cache)<-poll data from API and put in a cache.

```
ListComponent.html:16 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'input: -0.0006'. Current value: 'input: -0.0005943807529616154'.
    at viewDebugError (core.js:9817)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:9795)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:9962)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:14014)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:13984)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:14813)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14715)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ListComponent.html:16)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14697)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:13822)
```

Comment: Please add a stackblitz if possible.

Comment: I think the problem is a @ViewChild